# Add support for upmendex in arara

Tags: arara

This is not really a question, but more a suggestion to the authors of 'arara'.

I tried to find a way to contact Paulo Cereda (the author of 'arara'), but could not find that so quickly on the Internet.

I read for the first time about 'upmendex' in the book 'The Latex Companion - Third Edition' by Frank Mittelbach.

Upmendex is a program which can be used to generate Unicode based indices.

I would like a 'rule' in 'arara' for 'upmendex'.

Now I created one myself, by copying 'arara-rule-makeindex.yaml' and renaming it to 'arara-rule-upmendex.yaml' in folder 'C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules'.

I changed it to look like the following:

```
!config
# Arara, the cool TeX automation tool
# Copyright (c) 2023, Island of TeX
# All rights reserved.
#
# This rule is part of arara.
identifier: upmendex
name: UpMendex
authors:
- Hans Nieuwenhuis
commands:
- name: The UpMendex index software
  command: >
    @{
        base = getBasename(reference.fileName);
        infile = base.concat('.').concat(input[0]);
        outfile = [ '-o', base.concat('.').concat(output[0]) ];
        logfile = [ '-t', base.concat('.').concat(log[0]) ];
        return getCommand('upmendex', IgnoreLeadingAndTrailingBlanks, style, order, options,
                          logfile, infile, outfile);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: input
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.input
    }
  default: idx
- identifier: output
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.output
    }
  default: ind
- identifier: log
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.log
    }
  default: ilg
- identifier: IgnoreLeadingAndTrailingBlanks
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.IgnoreLeadingAndTrailingBlanks, '-c')
    }
- identifier: order
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'letter', 'word' ].contains(parameters.order)) {
            return isTrue(parameters.order == 'letter', '-l', '');
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided order is invalid.');
        }
    }
- identifier: style
  flag: "@{ [ '-s', parameters.style ] }"
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

And I'm using it as follows in a Latex file:

```
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no, shell: yes }
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no, shell: yes}
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no, shell: yes }
% arara: upmendex: { IgnoreLeadingAndTrailingBlanks: yes, style: MyIndexStyle.ist }
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no }
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: no }
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ log, aux, out, toc, ] }
```

The file 'MyIndexStyle.ist' looks as follows:

```
% This is the style file for generating an index using upmendex
% https://github.com/t-tk/upmendex-package

% show a big letter above each group of words starting with the same letter
headings_flag    1
heading_prefix   "\\hfill {\\Large --\\textbf{"
heading_suffix   "}--} \\hfill \\nopagebreak \n"

% right align page numbers
delim_0   "\\dotfill "
delim_1   "\\dotfill "
delim_2   "\\dotfill "
```

Feel free to use it until there is official support for 'upmendex' in 'arara' :-)

Comment: Paulo's not hard to find:-) but arara support contacts are at https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/